# Does intersection of shrinking sets 'converge' to its limit?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a Hilbert space and $K_n$ a sequence of closed convex sets in $E$. Assume $K_{n+1}\subset K_n$ for every $n$. And $$\cap_{n}K_n=K$$ and $K$ is non-empty. If we assume $K_n\neq K$ for any $n$ and then define $$d_n=\sup_{y\in K_n\setminus K}\inf_{x\in K}||x-y||.$$ My question is, does $d_n\to 0?.$

My hunch is yes it converges to $0$ but I cannot prove it. I try to proceed by induction. Since $d_n$ is non-increasing and bounded below by $0$. So its limit $d$ always exists. Then I assume $d>0$. I want to construct a point belongs to every $K_n$ i.e. in $K$ but have positive distance to $K$ from the assumption. But I am having difficulty proveing this. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look for "diameter 2 property"; it's a property of Banach spaces whereby all slices of the unit ball have diameter 2 (i.e. you can find nested convex closed sets, which are slices, whose diameter never shrinks).  They might provide a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in infinite dimensions. Take a properly nested sequence of closed subspaces $Y_n$ (i.e. $Y_{n + 1} \subsetneq Y_n$ for all $n$), and define $K_n = B_X \cap Y_n$, i.e. the closed unit ball of $Y_n$ centred at the origin. Note that $K_n$ are similarly nested, and $K$ is the unit ball of the closed subspace $\bigcap_n Y_n$.

Let $x_n \in Y_{n+1} \setminus Y_n^\perp$, and by normalising, assume without loss of generality that $\|x_n\| = 1$, and hence $x_n \in K$. Then $x_n$ projects onto $K_n$ at $0$, as $x_n \in Y_n^\perp$. This means that $x_n$ projects onto any closed subspace of $Y_n$ (including $\bigcap_n Y_n$) at $0$, and is distance $1$ from it. The same can be said of the unit balls of these subspaces.

Thus, with this construction, we have $d_n = 1$ for all $n$, and so $d_n$ need not converge to $0$.